# Button hovered and pressed ianages from normal button in CSS or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three buttons, one is a normal button image, another is a button image when the normal button is hovered, and the third button image is when the normal button is pressed.  My question is how to I transition to hovered and back to normal, and to pressed from normal images?  Can I use CSS with this or javascript a better solution?

Comment: The css is better, when it is possible. You can use css selectors to differentiate between states :hover :active etc.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple with CSS:

```
.my-button {
   // normal styles
}

.my-button:hover {
   // hover styles
}

.my-button:active {
   // active (clicked) button styles
}
```

If you're going to be using background images, a good trick is to use a button sprite sheet, and just transition the `background-position` based on the button state. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sprites_hover_nav) is an example.